# How access with recursion to some element of a struct

Tags: c, arrays, recursion, struct

I would write a function , that elaborates a struct and return the length of an array of character ,that is define in the same struct, in a recursive way.
The struct is:

```
typedef struct BinSeq {
char* data;              
int dimension;         
}BinSeq
```

data, the array of character,can have only two type of character: '0' and '1',while dimension is the length of array, but not of sequence of '0' and '1'.
So I try to write this function:

```
int length(BinSeq* bin_seq) {
   int i;
   if(bin_seq->data[i] == '0' || bin_seq->data[i] == '1')
   {
         i++;
         return 1 + length(bin_seq->data[i]);
    }else
             return 0;
}
```

but I have may doubts about this. First caused by the compiler that says:

```
warning: passing argument 1 of ‘length’ makes pointer from integer without a cast [enabled by default]
              return 1 + length(bin_seq->data[i]);
              ^
recursion.c:13:6: note: expected ‘struct BinSeq *’ but argument is of type ‘char’
  int length(BinSeq* bin_seq) {
```

How can I work on the data , If I had to pass to my function the Binseq* bin_seq? I know that my code is in error for this , but if I want calculate the leght I had to increment the variable i, but the it won't , I think, increase. How can I work on this?

Comment: You invoked *undefined behavior* by using a value of uninitialized variable having automatic storage duration `i`, which is indeterminate.

Comment: Sorry, but I coudl't get what you want clearly. `BinSeq` doesn't seem to have something like pointers to next node.

Comment: @MikeCat How can I work on the array data, if I had to pass to my function bin_seq, that is of type BinSeq?

Comment: There is no recursion in your `struct` and you compiler should warn about that code. They are not to be ignored, as many beginners seem to think. Your question is unclear.

Comment: I'm sorry if I have expose the problem in a bad way, I had to do experience there.

Comment: See [ask] and provide a [mcve].

Comment: Be careful for [The XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info/). Must you use recursion? Won't a simple loop or standard library work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct BinSeq {
    char *data;
    int dimension;
} BinSeq;

int length(BinSeq* bin_seq) {
    if(*bin_seq->data == '0' || *bin_seq->data == '1')
         return 1 + length(&(BinSeq){bin_seq->data + 1, bin_seq->dimension});

    return 0;
}

int main(int argc, char** argv) {  
    BinSeq binary;

    binary.data  = "0000110111";
    binary.dimension = 2014;

    int dimension_of_array = length(&binary);

    printf("%d\n", dimension_of_array);

    return 0;
}
```

---

by using the auxiliary recursive function

```
int aux_length(const char *data){
    if(*data == '0' || *data == '1')
         return 1 + aux_length(data + 1);

    return 0;
}

int length(BinSeq* bin_seq) {
    return aux_length(bin_seq->data);
}
```

Comment: Such a recursion is very wasteful.

Comment: So , first I must remember that I'm working with a pointer of type Binseq create by me.Then to "enter" in binseq I had to   use the Sintax that you have used there? &(BinSeq){bin_seq->data + 1, bin_seq->dimension}? Or Can I do that in a other way?

Comment: @MicheleColuccelli You can use local variable instead of `&(BinSeq){bin_seq->data + 1, bin_seq->dimension}`. E.g `BinSeq temp; temp.data = bin_seq->data + 1; temp.dimension=bin_seq->dimension;`... `return 1 + length(&temp);`

Comment: thank you, but i prefer the first actually. This seems to be only  a redundance....

Comment: Replication is required because the original can not be changed. BTW `temp.dimension=bin_seq->dimension;` does not need to actually. Because it does not use.

Comment: @MicheleColuccelli Or by using the auxiliary function. you can create a custom strlen recursive function.

Answer (score 0):

If I interpreted correctly, this code should do what you want:

```
int length(BinSeq* bin_seq, int i) {
   if(bin_seq->data[i] == '0' || bin_seq->data[i] == '1')
   {
         return 1 + length(bin_seq->data, ++i);
   } else {
         return 0;
   }
}
```

Although there are more efficient ways to code this: in practice you can simply use pointer arithmetic to loop over the `char` array until you find anything but a 0 or 1. You have also not shown how you initialize the sequence; one would assume it is done correctly with a known terminator character (e.g. `\0`).

Comment: I had to write this function: int lenght(BinSeq* bin_seq), with this prototipo. Probably I had to reformulate my question, is unclear.

Answer (score 0):

I had to write a function int length(BinSeq* bin_seq)that calculates recursively the length of the binary sequence bin_seq. The struct is:

```
typedef struct BinSeq {
char* data;              
int dimension;         
}BinSeq
```

and the main is:

```
   int main(int argc, char** argv) {  
       Binseq* binary;
       binary.data  = "0000110111";
       binary.dimension = 2014;
       int dimension_of_array = length(BinSeq* bin_seq);
   }
```

How can I calculate the length of data, if I had to pass bin_seq to function?

Comment: You should edit your question rather than ask another question in an "answer," mainly because it would be difficult for somebody else to follow the conversation. I will edit my answer to address this clarification.